# ArgumentException thrown in system OnTouch event

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have a simple application with two pages on it. The first page acts normally, and I have a button on the page that navigates to the second page.

However, when I get to the second page, any time I try to touch anything, the `OnTouch` event fires and an `ArgumentException` is thrown in the `ListDictionaryInternal`

However, I have nothing on the page that interacts with this OnTouch event, so I'm not sure what could be causing it.

The code to navigate to the new page:

```
string page = "valid";
NavigationService.Navigate(
    new Uri("/Dialog.xaml?page=" + page,
    UriKind.Relative)
);
```

The XAML of the page that crashes is very simple:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Name="AppName" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Name="PageName" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Click="CancelDownload_Click" Opacity="1.0" Content="Cancel REST Request!" Background="Blue" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Black" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="CancelData" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="90,327,90,291" Height="150" Width="300" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

What could be causing the OnTouch to fail in such a way?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you register OnTouch in PhoneApplicationPage? What do you do in OnTouch handler? And try to rebuild your project

Comment: No I do no have any OnTouch handler in any of my PhoneApplicationPages, which makes the error confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, thee was a hack from the main page I had used to disable the scrolling of PivotItems when interacting with a nested Panorama.

The code that caused the error:

```
Touch.FrameReported += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(MainItems).Action == TouchAction.Up)
    {
        MainItems.IsHitTestVisible = true;
    }
};
```